# Microsoft RDP client for mac and protocol version 7.1

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, mac-osx, rdp

I have the problem that I cannot connect to a Windows 2008 R2 (SP1) server via RDP using my Mac. 
The error Message I get is the following: “You were disconnected from the Windows-based computer because of problems during the licensing protocol”

From asking Mr. Google I tried the proposed solution to delete some cached files, but it didn’t resolve the problem.

The strange thing is that to other S
servers running Windows 2008 R2 (SP1) on the same Network I can connect.

I checked the configuration on the server and noticed that under Roles -> Remote Desktop Services -> RD Session Host Configuration it says under Connection Type: “Microsoft RDP 7.1”. On other server where I can connect it says “Microsoft RDP 6.1”.

Could that be the reason?

The Mac I use has Lion 10.7.3 installed

Bye,
Martin

Comment: Are you using the 1.0.3 or 2.1.1 client?  You might be having issues using the older client.  Just a thought.  http://www.microsoft.com/mac/downloads

Comment: Check that your server is registered with a correct RDP license server

Comment: @Mike I'm using the newer one 2.1.1.

Comment: @MathieuChateau It is connected to a correct RDP license server I double checked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. You will have to wait for the hotfix from either MS or apple. Use CORD the open source RDP client. I manage several terminal servers and some macs cannot connect. MS has acknowledged the issue.

Comment: Ok got in contact with MS support and they told me exactly the same. We have to wait until they release the hotfix.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest rdp client 2.1.2

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18309066/rdc_2.1.2_120917_release_enu_ship_clean_standard_retail_redlab_120917-apex-build-XS26-.dmg

Comment: just tried this and it works fine. checks clean on virustotal in case anyone is concerned. https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/ce9c9e7193b4c15e4331dc7adbb1fe2112ed36bf9b188e973cf0cabba827df19/analysis/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - have this Trouble today 
RPD 7.1 in a full patched 2008R2 Server
an NO official RDC Pack higher than 2.1.1

So you can use CoRD (http://cord.sourceforge.net/)
We´ve tried and it worked fine for "normal" user RDP Connection

Greetings from Hamburg/Germany
Lutz